# Change Formatting Of Phone Numbers in AD Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I saw many great posts about this but having great difficulty tailoring it for my situation.

I have an OU where I want to format all phone and mobile numbers differently as required by the organisation. From what I can tell there are currently 2 formats of phone numbers

- `03XXXXXXXX`
- `+61 3 XXXX XXXX`

The second version is what we need for all phone numbers.

For mobile we currently have 3 formats

- `04XXXXXXXX`
- `04XX XXX XXX`
- `+61 4XX XXX XXX`

What I'm finding tricky is that all phone numbers must start with `+61 3` and mobile numbers with `+61 4`

Most of the numbers in AD have a `0` at the beginning which will need to removed.

So an example - `0399998888` will turn to `+61 3 9999 888`

Mobile - `0411333555` will turn to `+61 411 333 555`

This is what I have for phone numbers but it's not working

```
    Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU" -Filter "telephoneNumber -like '03*'" -Properties telephoneNumber | select name, telephoneNumber

    Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU" -Filter "telephoneNumber -like '03*'" -Properties telephoneNumber | Where { $_.telephoneNumber -match '^\\d{10}\$'} | Foreach {Set-ADUser $_ -Replace @{TelephoneNumber=( $_.telephoneNumber -replace '^\(\d{1})\)(\s\d{4})-(\d{4})', '+61 $1 $2 $3') }  -whatIf }

    Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU" -Filter "telephoneNumber -like '03*'" -Properties telephoneNumber | Where { $_.telephoneNumber -match '^\\d{10}\$'} | Foreach {Set-ADUser $_ -Replace @{TelephoneNumber=( $_.telephoneNumber -replace '^\(\d{1})\)(\s\d{4})-(\d{4})', '+61 $1$2 $3') }  }

    Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU" -Filter "telephoneNumber -like '+61*'" -Properties telephoneNumber | select name, telephoneNumber
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT: This is the code I used that managed to get it working

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU" -Filter "telephoneNumber -like '03*'" -Properties telephoneNumber |
    ForEach-Object {
        $PhoneNumberRaw = $_.telephoneNumber -replace '^0' -replace '^\+61' -replace '\s' -as [LONG]
        $newPhoneNumber = if ($PhoneNumberRaw -match '^3') {
                            "+61 {0:# #### ####}" -f $PhoneNumberRaw
                        }
                        else {
                            "+61 {0:### ### ###}" -f $PhoneNumberRaw
                        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $_.Name
            TelephoneNumber = $newPhoneNumber
        }
    $Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU" -Filter "telephoneNumber -like '03*'" -Properties telephoneNumber, distinguishedName
        ForEach ($User In $Users)
    {
        $DN = $User.distinguishedName
        Set-ADUser -Identity $DN -OfficePhone $newPhoneNumber
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To run the same query against your AD again and again is very inefficient. I would apporach it a little bit different. First you take the telphone number as i t is and remove everything you actually don't need (what's not unique) then you differentiate between mobile and landline and then you simply format it the way you need ... like this maybe

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "telephonenumber -like '*'" -SearchBase 'OU' -Properties telephoneNumber | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $PhoneNumberRaw = $_.telephoneNumber -replace '^0' -replace '^\+61' -replace '\s' -as [LONG]
        $newPhoneNumber = if ($PhoneNumberRaw -match '^3') {
                            "+61 {0:# #### ####}" -f $PhoneNumberRaw
                        }
                        else {
                            "+61 {0:### ### ###}" -f $PhoneNumberRaw
                        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $_.Name
            TelephoneNumber = $newPhoneNumber
        }
        Set-ADUser -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -OfficePhone $newPhoneNumber -WhatIf
    }
```

Of course I could not test it in my environment because we surely have a complete different telephone system but I tested the logic for the numbers.
The `-as [LONG]` was necessary for the `-f` operator to recognize the digits. 
If you want to make the actual changes to the AD you will have to remove the `-WhatIf`. And of course for the change of the AD you would not need to create a custom object.

Comment: Thanks Olaf! 

I tried running that script but it comes up asking for a filter. I tried telephonenumber but it said invalid argument

Comment: and ... did you add one and tried it again? (I added the filter in the code above)

Comment: Yes it outputs the correct change which is great but how do I get it to actually change the phone number in AD?

Comment: Thanks Olaf, I modified it as best I could to also take care of mobile numbers. How do I make this apply in AD instead of just giving me an output?

Also seems like it is affixing +61 to all users even if they don't have a phone number.

is there a way to only target users that have telephone or mobile numbers specified?

Thanks

Comment: I updatd the code in my answer.   ...  If you like to get only the accounts with _something_ in the attribute _telephoneNmuber_ you have to add a filter for this. And to _write_ the changed number to the AD you have to use a _set_ cmdlet like `Set-ADUser`. The according parameter is named `OfficePhone`. To actually _release_ the change to the AD you will have to remove the `WhatIf` from the code.

Comment: I would recommend for you to make small step back and take a little time to start to learn the very basics of Powershell from scratch. That's even free of charge and slightly entertaining when you do the video course at the [Microsoft Virtual Academy: Getting Started with Powershell](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start-8276?l=r54IrOWy_2304984382). That would save you from a lot of wasted time and frustration. And I'm sure it would pay off for you in the future.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, with some research, trial and error I now have some code that appears to work and also sets it in AD. I have added this to my original post.

Comment: With the code you posted you will get __ONLY__ accounts with telephonenumbers starting with __03__ - nothing else. I thought you wanted to catch almost everything and bring it to a common format. This way you could even simplify your code much more. ;-)

Comment: Yeah I haven't got time to delve too deep into this lol I will just modify the script to catch other variations!

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: So why don't you use the code I posted. It should do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Did you remove the `WhatIf` at the end of the `Set-ADUser` command?